# How to configure app-name for website shortcut (homescreen)?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, metadata

I´m having a website my client wants to add to his home screen on android, so when I´m doing this (with chrome), chrome/android asks to provide/change the displayed name. In my case it is prefilled with "App".

The label of the popup translated to english is "Add to Homesceen"
[image: my case]

But when I do the same with for-example **stackoverflow** I get 
it prefilled with a "name" probably the site title.
[image: example case]

so what I tried:

- I have a title tag and tried to shorten it, but even with very small title theres still "App" by default
- I added a `<meta name="application-name" content="name-X">` with no effect, also tried `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="name-X">`
- checked the markup which validates with no errors/warning (w3c-validator)
- App-icons for different devices and sizes work as expected
- and I tried to search the web with no success :/
- I can´t even Figure out where "App" may come from as its not occuring in source

for any help thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe this link can help you : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts You can then configure the shortcut name you want in the section '@string'.

Comment: thanks for elaborating on this, but can a website have an android app manifest as well? This article looks like dedicated to native android apps, but i´m having a website

Comment: @johnSmith this question has been asked already on SO - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41974009/1675954 . As well as requiring a manifest file, you will need a 'service worker' javascript file (detailed in the answer)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for a [PWA JSON manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/). It will tell your browser about your app.

As you can see in the link above, you shall provide **short_name** and/or **name** attribute. Don't forget to link your manifest:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Example:

```
{
  "short_name": "Maps",
  "name": "Google Maps",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icons-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/maps/?source=pwa",
  "background_color": "#3367D6",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/maps/",
  "theme_color": "#3367D6"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, thats exactly what I was looking for :-) I also added an empty-service worker, dont know if that was neccessary too but it´s working now as expected!