# ADD to HOME SCREEN

Tags: javascript, json, service-worker, manifest.json

I try to understand, it is certain that I do not have rich knowledge but I want to complete this.
in conclusion, I created manifest.json and service-worker.js
in manifest.json I put

```
{
  "short_name": "xyx",
  "name": " ccccc ",
  "theme_color": "#4A90E2",
  "background_color": "#F7F8F9",
  "display": "standalone",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-32.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "32x32"
    },
      {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-64.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "64x64"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-96.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-128.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-168.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "168x168"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-256.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "256x256"
    },
     {
      "src": "/images/icons/icon-512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/?utm_source=launcher"
}
```

and in service-worker.js I put

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {  
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}
```

What else do I have to do or add for ADD TO HOME SCREEN to appear on my mobile phone ??

Comment: Can you add the content of your serviceworker?

Comment: yes, but I don't know what to put on them, I kept looking but I didn't find anything clear.

Comment: You're missing all the logic inside your service-worker.js The best you can do is do some more research on how to make a PWA, a good starting point is: [HERE](https://medium.com/james-johnson/a-simple-progressive-web-app-tutorial-f9708e5f2605). Be aware that showing to popup to install the app on your device is not up to you but to the Browser. It will only be shown if you meet all the [criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369951/how-to-get-add-to-home-screen-pop-up-on-site-open-in-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to rename it to `manifest.webmanifest` its commonly.

Do you also linked it to your app like this?:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
```

Then check if its applied:

[image]

If you did everything correct check if the install button appear.

This website is: https://nuxtjs.org/

[image]

Comment: the manifest works, and the service worker is visible but that add to screen doesn't appear to me

Comment: on the searchbar, on the right, do you see on the image that star witch creates a read tab? if your app provieds an PWA to install, a little `+` symbol will appear witch you can click to install it

Comment: ok, the add button appears and works. I was thinking about that popup. https://i.imgur.com/Sefx5JC.jpg