# Is there a possibility to create a iOS or Android shortcut by pressing a link?

Tags: android, ios, url

Is there a possibility to create an iOS or Android shortcut by pressing a link on a website?
I want to create a deeplink as shortcut on the homescreen for my customers.

Answer (score 1):

For the Android app you could use a button.

On `Button` click event listener write this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

that open the your URL.

I cannot help you for iOS.

Comment: I edited my post by specifing the link topic. I mean a link on a website and your code is for an app isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. 

This should help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369951/how-to-get-add-to-home-screen-pop-up-on-site-open-in-mobile-browser