# What is wrong with this Lighthouse audit? Can I install a PWA from http://localhost

Tags: javascript, mobile, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I have a PWA that passes the Lighthouse audit on Chrome for an installable PWA but I never get prompted to install it and the "beforeinstallprompt" event never fires. Just checked Opera and that doesn't ask me to install either :-(

I am developing/debugging with http://localhost, which seems suitable for other tests, could this be the problem? I want to test my bespoke install prompt locally before deployment.

Manifest: -

```
{
  "short_name": "Brotkrumen",
  "name": "Brotkrumen Web App",
  "description": "Native Background Geolocation POC",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "gingerbreadhouse.png",
      "sizes": "48x48 128x128 144x144 192x192 512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "gingerbreadhouse.png",
      "sizes": "48x48 128x128 144x144 192x192 512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/travelmanager.html",
  "background_color": "#00ccdd",
  "theme_color": "#00ccdd",
  "display": "fullscreen"
}
```

Lighthouse Audit: -

[image]

***Edit 1***

**Please Note**: - The https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen repository can be cloned by anyone! Just stick it in a internet facing folder/directory and go for "https://your.domain/TravelManager.html" You'll need a Google Maps API key to use the maps and at least a couple of GPS readings before you can press "Arrive".

NB: With Edge I do get prompted to install via the beforeinstall event https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen/blob/master/TravelManager.html Line# 117 but not Chrome

@Fawaz are you sure you haven;t added chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks ? It's just that I've invoke your web-site multiple times and it hasn't asked me to install. Have you tried Chrome on another PC?

***Edit 2***

School boy error :-( Pretty sure I cleared my BrotkrumenV1 cache before it "magically" started working. Coincidence? I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see Add to homescreen on http://localhost (I tested on Desktop chrome browser, and it shows install App option)

This is the [build code](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/askgod/tree/main/docs) for my App.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65082386/2437224) might be relevant to you.

Comment: Hi Fawaz, just to clarify, your App/PWA promted you to *install* not the old "add to homescreen" when you were serving the app from http:/locallhost/askgod/ and NOT httpS:localhost/askgod/ ? Would you have a screen shot available to add to your reply please?

Comment: @McMurphy Yes, it prompted to install, here's the screenshots:
 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fawazahmed0/tiger/master/Screenshot%20(175).png

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fawazahmed0/tiger/master/Screenshot%20(176).png

Comment: Thanks Fawaz! For the 50 points and more could you *please* (first edit your original answer so I can up your votes and then) Run a lighthouse audit on your http:// version (not httpS://)? It looks like Chrome. Can you also please confirm it is Chrome? I just saw that mine works with Edge but not Chrome, or Opera - Strange. Oh and you didn't set that "Bypass user enganement checks" flag did you?

Comment: Yes I am on chrome 91, Here's my lighthouse audit:
https://github.com/fawazahmed0/tiger/releases/download/v2/localhost_1699-20210718T185247.html 
I haven't set any 'Bypass checks'.

Comment: Mate, you don't have "PWA Optimized" lit up, you still have red triangles, and yet your app installs? What am I doing wrong? Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you followed all the steps given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65082386/2437224
You also need to have a service worker registered.
Also if incase you are using parcel, you can serve the files over https:
parcel index.html --https

Comment: Here's my manifest:
https://github.com/fawazahmed0/askgod/blob/main/manifest.webmanifest
and my service worker:
https://github.com/fawazahmed0/askgod/blob/main/service-worker.js
and here I am registering the service worker:
https://github.com/fawazahmed0/askgod/blob/27a99388c70946abfbdb3637abddb80bc3a88310/v3.js#L97

Comment: Please see Edit 1

Comment: @McMurphy Make sure you are on latest version of chrome (version 91) , your code works fine for me. see the screenshots in this folder:
https://github.com/fawazahmed0/tiger/tree/master/screeenshotsd

Comment: but you simply can't ask everyone in the world to set the chrome://flags/#bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks flag. Does that not strike you as a prohibitive restriction? Anyway I'll code to Chrome and worry more when I'm httpS

Comment: It's default value, I did not set the bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks flag
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fawazahmed0/tiger/master/screeenshotsd/Screenshot%20(177).png

Comment: Ok @Fawaz, I appologoze for doubting you. All of a sudden (honestly the last change was just to set HTML and BODY height to 100% for Firefox so max-min height would agree to moz-available) and now I'm being prompted. Strange!. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

To make the website installable, it has to be served from a secure (HTTPS) domain. You can run localhost on HTTPS using mkcert.
For more info :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Installable_PWAs

Comment: Localhost is the exception to that rule for everything else ServiceWorker etc. Do you have areference that says the httpS rule is enforced for localhost ONLY on the install event?